# What is `haste` config in jest-preset for React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am unable to find *any* documentation on the format for jest-preset.json. Specifically, I am trying to find out what the `haste` option does:

*node_modules/react-native/jest-preset.json*

```
{
  "haste": {
    "defaultPlatform": "ios",
    "platforms": ["android", "ios", "native"],
    "hasteImplModulePath": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js",
    "providesModuleNodeModules": [
      "react-native"
    ]
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^React$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
  },
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4|png|psd|svg|webp)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/assetFileTransformer.js"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element)"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```